# How to plot pie chart for bivariate data in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a data frame:

```
level type count
A      00   123
B      00   542
C      00   985
D      00   786
A      01   423
B      01   552
C      01   785
D      01   686 
A      02   523
B      02   642
C      02   385
D      02   86
```

I want four pie charts under 4 different levels: each pie chart has data about different types 00,01,02 etc.

```
A  - pie chart1 contains information about different 'type'
B  - pie chart2 contains information about different 'type'
C  - pie chart3 contains information about different 'type'
D  - pie chart4 contains information about different 'type'
```

In fact I have to make this dynamic. Only different levels are e.g. A, ...D are fixed. But different types 00,01,...09,10 can go to many types depending on data frames I will pick. I have to process multiple dataframes and they have same Level but different types.

I tried to use groupby on df but it didn't work.

```
df = df.groupby(['level', 'type']).size().unstack(fill_value=0)
```

Comment: For that matter, don't forget to add in what exactly you are expecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That will work!

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'level': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
                   'type': ['00', '00', '00', '00', '01', '01', '01', '01', '02', '02', '02', '02'],
                   'count':[123, 542, 985, 789, 423, 552, 785, 686, 523, 642, 385, 85]})

# Group it
group_df = df.groupby(['level'])    

for name, group in group_df:
    ax = group.groupby(['type']).sum().plot(kind='pie', y='count', legend=None, title=name)
    ax.set_ylabel(name)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: In this legend repeats for each pie chart. Is there a way that legend will publish only once and instead of y='count', is it possibe to publish 'name' alogside each pie chart? I inserted y='name' but it gives error.

Comment: I've edited my answer to add title and change ylable. I also removed legend. It's much more difficult to add 1 legend. So I suggest choosing from multiple legends vs no legend.

Comment: can you please guide to which package I can see the method plot() you have used, so that I can manipulate the color choices etc. It is not from matplotlib.

Comment: plot method in my code is Pandas API for matplotlib. You can provide a lot of kwargs from matplotlib to plot method. Or you can assign return of plot method to variable, in my case that's ax. And work with it as in matplotlib.

Comment: If there is no legend then how can I know which portion of pie chart is what? It doesn't make any sense.